# 轉子 In the context of Danganronpa…?

Tags: traditional-characters

I was playing Danganronpa v3, the version from Taiwan. Tenko says “因為到這裡來以後,就沒什麼機會活動筋骨 所以轉子剛剛去體育館稍微嫩餘一下! “. What does “轉子“  mean in this context? I know “大轉子“ means trochanter in the context of anatomy and “轉子“ in the context of electronics means rotor. Can anyone give me a better translation of the sentence? I’m stumped. Thank you.

Comment: In the text, it seems to be the name of a character.

Comment: Tenko Chabashira maybe

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid you having to google it in depth and possibly find game spoilers (why is danganronpa such an easy to spoil series by fans?)

Here is a photo of the character named 轉子:

[image]

Comment: for a rough translation: since coming here, I haven't had much chance to exercise.  So I came to the gym  to exercise for a little while. (using name in third person to be cutesy).